# Why do we need non-anchor peers for same organization in Hyperledger Fabric

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I was trying to understand role of Anchor Peers in Hyperledger fabric. I have understood that we can have multiple anchor peers in same Organization to prevent single point of failure.

https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.1/glossary.html#anchor-peer

If that is the case, then why do we even need non-anchor peers in same organization? Is there any significance of having non-anchor peers in same organization?

Answer (score 3):

You can certainly have all your peers that participate in a channel to be anchor peers.

However keep in mind that you might not want all your peers to be exposed to the other organizations from all kinds of reasons. Such peers shouldn't be anchor peers and shouldn't have external endpoints.

Comment: Thank You. However; Lets assume we have one anchor peer and one non-anchor peer. If one anchor peer is down, then how come we can achieve HA. will non-anchor peer become anchor peer automatically if anchor peer is down?

Comment: No... but the anchor peers are only needed for initial membership establishment. Afterwards they are not.

Comment: Sorry, but now its more confusing. If anchor peers are only needed for initial membership establishment, then again I am not able to understand how non-anchor peer will be available if anchor peer is down. non-anchor peer is not needed for initial membership.

Comment: because - once you have the membership - the peers know each other, and then you don't need the anchor peer anymore.